# UILabel height depending on font size

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, constraints, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am using a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell` to display a title. Normally the text is not too long and therefore the font size can be large. Notice how the text fills the height of the`UILabel` like normal.

[image]

However, when there is a larger title, I want the `UILabel` height to reduce to accommodate the smaller font size and not leave a blank gap in its place. Currently, my configuration produces this effect.

[image]

I am using constraints in my storyboard and have deliberately not set a fixed height constraint. Here are the relevant constraints added:

[image]

I may have made a rookie error in my configuration as I can't remember this effect happening before, but it is giving me real headaches (and a bad looking UI).

Comment: Depending on the other constraints on the other subviews, you could adjust the vertical content hugging priority. Increase it on the label.

Comment: @jervine10 The title label has the highest vertical content hugging priority over any other subviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `UILabel` is set to auto-adjust font size to fit, it does NOT auto-adjust the ***height*** of itself.

You have a couple options:

1. set Baseline to Align Centers, and just accept that you will have top and bottom padding
2. use code to calculate the "scaled font size" and update the font size of the label

Answer (score 0):

Remove either the `Top Space` or `Bottom Space` constraints (depending on where you want the label to be anchored).

This will cause the label to automatically use fit itself to the text size.

Comment: But then how would my table view know the height of which to display the row at?

Comment: You can either set the `rowHeight` in code or Interface Builder. If you need a different row height for each row depending on the cell's content you can use the [`heightForRowAt:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview) method of `UITableViewDelegate`

Comment: I want to use the preferred UITableViewAutomaticDimension which I have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see, it should work according to your need:

[image]

Set Top and Bottom constraints attribute `Greater Than or Equal To` and add horizontal center (Alight Center Y to superview) and show in this image.